# how to combine dataframes generated by loop

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I started a loop to generates dataframe from json in a folder.

```
for filename in os.listdir('json1'):
with open(os.path.join('json1',filename),'r') as json_data:
    d=json.load(json_data)
    df2=pd.io.json.json_normalize(d)
    df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
    df3=pd.io.json.json_normalize(d['Reviews'])
    df3.columns = df3.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
    df4=pd.concat([df2]*df3.shape[0],ignore_index=True)
    df5=df4.join(df3)
    print(df5)
```

The result that I print contains the dataframe that generated for each json file in the folder. However, I am wondering how can I combine all of these dataframe into a single big dataframe. They all have similar columns head but may slightly different.

Comment: To be more specific, what I want is combine df5 that generated by each json file into a big single dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```
def my_read_json(filename, **kwargs):
    # ...
    return df5

df = pd.concat([my_read_json(f) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it does generate a big dataframe, however, it seems like it is repeating the first dataframe n times. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: @ruw011, make sure that the function returns correct Df, that was read from JSON file

Comment: I thought it might caused by where I put the return. So I changed it and I got duplicates of the last dataframe

Comment: and the 'files' in concat code should be filename right?

Comment: @ruw011, yes, it should be a list of filenames

Comment: I try to insert the function below with open to make sure that it returns each df5, however I get I/O operation on closed file error. Do you have any idea why is that?